# put process indicator on h:commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow-2

Currently we are using  and My goal is to prevent system from double click problem and also gives users a sign that system is in process - because system is gonna calculate lots o things after user clicks that h:commandButton.

**Button Code:**

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="ux_link_text" 
               action="Account" value="Account Info" 
               target="_blank" />
```

Please advise me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` in the `onclick` property of the `<h:commandbutton>`. This will disable the button 100 milliseconds after being clicked and the action invoked.

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="ux_link_text" 
               action="Account" value="Account Info" 
               target="_blank"                
               onclick="setTimeout(this.disabled = true;, 100);"/>
```

More info:

- [How to do double click prevention in JSF ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756426/how-to-do-double-click-prevention-in-jsf-2)

Comment: @kocko..I will test it and let you know. One more thing, Can we also make other links disable on the same screen by setTimeout? I mean to say that If I have two link and whenever I click any link, than selected link and other remain disable.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. You can create a JavaScript function for the purpose, where you will find the components you want to disable by their id then disable them.