# The following objects may have been concurrently modified in another transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have jsf page that has button when I click this button it calls method that update object 
exist in the database. when I click this button twice I get this exception. I searched for it 
too much but I didn't find any related answer.
I am using JPA 2.0
this is the full exception message

```
[4/10/14 10:36:54:532 EDT] 00000138 RegisteredSyn E   WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: <openjpa-1.2.4-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1481680 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Optimistic locking errors were detected when flushing to the data store.  The following objects may have been concurrently modified in another transaction: [com.ibm.pp.epad.cmt.domain.Brief-1]
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2184)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2031)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:1927)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1845)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.ComponentContextSynchronizationWrapper.beforeCompletion(ComponentContextSynchronizationWrapper.java:65)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.coreDistributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:289)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:150)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.prePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:2353)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:559)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:986)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:920)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:436)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:161)
at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit(TranStrategy.java:952)
at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:259)
at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:570)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4558)
at com.ibm.pp.epad.ejb.sessionbeans.EJSLocal0SLbriefService_92ef595f.updateBrief(EJSLocal0SLbriefService_92ef595f.java)
at com.ibm.pp.epad.controller.EditBriefController.saveBrief(EditBriefController.java:369)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:159)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:937)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:271)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1249)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:675)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656)
```

Can you help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is viewed 13 time and no reply. please I need help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, it happens when you quickly click the button twice?

In that case there are several ways of doing it, e.g. [here](http://www.rbecker.eu/2012/12/preventing-double-clicks-duplicate.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756426/how-to-do-double-click-prevention-in-jsf-2)

Answer (score 0):

User @Version field in your entity to handle optimistic locking.

Check this: https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and