# Primefaces CommandButton disable and enable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:commandButton id .......
onclick=”disableButton(this);”
onkeypress=”disableButton(this);”
oncomplete="enableButton('${bean.enableButton()}');"

private boolean enableButton(){
  return false;
}

<script>
function disableButton(data) {
  data.disable = true;
}

function enableButton(data) {
  data.disable = data;
}
</script>
```

Observed both calls working in the debugger, but the button remains disabled
When disableButton is called data = button#MessageView  j_idt183:….
When enableButton is called data = {url: “ ……….}
from the debugger

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do double-click prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756426/how-to-do-double-click-prevention-in-jsf)

Comment: Jasper, thanks for reviewing my question, unfortunately your suggestion was tried prior to my submission.

Comment: What do you mean with "your suggestion". The linked question has several answers. None of them worked for you? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: "Does this answer your question? How to do double-click prevention in JSF".  I've tried numerous solutions.

Comment: Try https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/renderers/commandButtonSingleClick.jsf

Comment: org.primefaces.extensions.renderer.CommandButtonSingleClickRenderer class not found

Comment: You'll need to add the library / dependency

Comment: Thanks, of course adding the library is one solution and obvious.  Unfortunately, we are too far down the development path to add additional COTS

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/60372180/880619 You don't need to add the library per se.

Comment: We are constrain to use Primefaces 6.1, should of noted it earlier

Comment: Does not matter. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/60372180/880619

Comment: The link you suggested - the section -  presents the same problem with dependency on class.  And attempted every example to no avail included in the entire question

Comment: Not if you copy the class, as you can read in the answer.

Comment: final String widgetVar = button.resolveWidgetVar(context);  The method resolveWidgetVar() in the type CommandButton is not applicable for the arguments(FacesContext)

Answer (score 1):

```
<p:commandButton id .......
   onclick=”disableButton(this);”
   onkeypress=”disableButton(this);”
   oncomplete="enableButton();"
<script>

function disableButton(data) {
  data.disable = true;
  window.buttonPressed.disabled = data
}
// Save and use the initial "data" object 
function enableButton() {
   window.buttonPressed.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).